# Calendar Approval Flow

Tags: workflow, calendar

If a member adds an item to a calendar I want a workflow to first check if that user is an admin, and if so I want that calendar item to be automatically added without a workflow...

Then begin the normal process

My sharepoint designer does not have "if user is part of a group"

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just uninherit the permissions on the calendar list so that admins are able to contribute and everyone else can just view (if that was your intention)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling a Web Service from your sharePoint desinger workflow, you'll need the SharePoint UserGroup.asmx service and the GetGroupCollectionFromUser web method.

Answer (score 0):

Use an impersonation step inside of SharePoint Designer.  Design and save the workflow as someone with highest permission level and the workflow will run at that level.  Then the permissions for all users can be checked with the following step:  If Created By -

[image]

Then click on the specific person link and you can choose a SharePoint group.  If all of your admins are in a group, this is possible.

Check at the bottom of [SPD Workflow Condition Quick Reference Guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-conditions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff) for information on impersonation steps.